# Button onclick replace with DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace button with a DIV in template design of my blog.
The code for button is

```
<button onClick="menu1.toggle();" class="sideviewtoggle fa fa-bars"></button>
```

And jquery script I am using for it is

```
jQuery(function(){ // on DOM load
    menu1 = new sidetogglemenu({  // initialize first menu example
        id: 'togglemenu1',
        marginoffset: 10,
        downarrowsrc: 'toggledown.png'
    })

})
```

It opens a siedbar toggle menu on click. I don't want to use `<button>` tag for this purpose, instead I want to use a `<div>` tag so that the  functions onclick instead of button. I think that it can be done by using a small code of Javascript but as I am new to Javascript so unable to do it myself?
What should I do?
Here is the url to template.
http://testing-prov4.blogspot.com

Comment: have you tried changing the `<button></button>` to `<div></div>` this should work

Comment: Simply replace the button tag with a div. Leave the onclick on it and set a value inside the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would like to use a `div` element to trigger the slideout menu instead of a `button` element. This can be easily accomplished. Your current code reads:

```
<button class='sideviewtoggle fa fa-bars' onClick='menu1.toggle();'></button>
```

You can replace this with:

```
<div class='sideviewtoggle fa fa-bars' onClick='menu1.toggle();'></div>
```

without changing any functionality. (CSS changes just a bit)